# Is euler's identity invalid in this case?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

in "Introductory Quantum Mechanics" by Richard L. Liboff, question 1.21 part o asks the reader to derive the following sum.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{L} e^{-i\frac{2\pi n}{L}} = 0
$$

The given hint asks the reader to separate n from the other powers and treat the expression as a geometric sum. Using the geometric sum equation, proving that expression is trivial.

However, I'm a bit confused as to why using euler's identity here doesn't work. To elaborate:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{L} \exp{(-i\frac{2\pi n}{L})} = 0
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{L} \exp{(-i2\pi)}^{\frac{n}{L}} = 0
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{L} (1)^{\frac{n}{L}} = 0
$$

Except that last equation is not true. I tried searching around the internet but I couldn't find a reason why im not allowed to use $\exp(-i2\pi) = 1$ here.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, is $-1=e^{\pi\mathrm{i}}=\left(e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{1}=1$?

Comment: In complex numbers, it is not true in general that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposed identity

$a^{(bc)}=(a^b)^c$

*does* hold in complex variables if $c$, the factor separated out of the exponent, is an integer.

We may therefore use this identity provided that $n$, and only $n$, is separated from the exponent. Then

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^L\exp(-i2\pi n/L)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^L[\exp(-i2\pi/L)]^n$

You then apply the geometric sequence sum formula to the right side, rendering the first term and common ratio as $\exp(-i2\pi/L)$. You should then get a fraction with a zero numerator and a nonzero denominator for all $L\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge2}$, proving the claim.

Answer (score 7):

By your reasoning, we could show that all powers are equal to $1$; e.g.,
$$e^z = (e^{2\pi i})^{z/(2\pi i)} = 1^{z/(2\pi i)} = 1.$$
Where is the flaw?  Clearly, the second equality is suspect:
$$e^{ab} \overset{?}{=} (e^a)^b.$$
Indeed, this isn't even true in the real numbers:
$$-8 = (-2)^3 = (-2)^{2(3/2)} = ((-2)^2)^{3/2} = 4^{3/2} = 2^3 = 8.$$

Answer (score 1):

(a) For the case with complex numbers:

$$
i=i^1 = i^{\frac{4}{4}}=(i^4)^{\frac{1}{4}} = 1^{\frac{1}{4}} = \sqrt[4]{1} = 1
$$
Which is obviously incorrect, with the mistake being:
$$i^\frac{4}{4}\neq (i^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
In the case of:

$$z^{\frac{a}b{}}$$
Here it matters on the $\gcd(a,b)$:

If $$\gcd(a,b)=1 \implies z^\frac{a}{b} = (z^a)^\frac{1}{b}$$

(b) Also should be mentioned non-invertible exponentiation, for example:

$$a=a^1=a^{\frac{2}{2}} \neq \sqrt {a^2}$$
Since $$\sqrt{a^2}= |a|$$